# Requesting extended permissions for Facebook pages

Tags: facebook

Does anyone here knows how to request extended permissions for a Facebook page using the new authorization mechanism for use with the old REST API?

The documentation tells that you need to redirect the current user to this url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?
    client_id=...&
    redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/callback&
    scope=publish_stream
```

This will request `publish_stream` permissions for the current user's wall but won't allow the use of the stream.publish API to write on a page's wall...

I suspect there's a bunch of additional query parameters to pass in the URL but the documentation is oblivious, any idea anyone?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ask a user to give permissions to administer all their pages, you need to request for "manage_pages" extended permission as described [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api#impersonation).

Comment: I realize the question is incomplete. Actually the new authorization mechanism is used to request permissions but the app is using the old REST API to post to a page.